# Sampler after While controller is not executing

Tags: jmeter

There is a problem that I have a jdbc request to execute but not succeed.
I elaborated problem in attached screenshot

Please Help ! 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZk3f.png)

Comment: I guess your while controller never stops because the condition is always evaluated as true.

Comment: It stops , I have verified that there were 3 records in CSV file , in view result tree displaying 3 executed request only that means loop stops..

Comment: Do you have a csv config setting in your test plan? If so, check if you set "stop thread" on file end.

Comment: Yes..I already did this...if I add anothet thread  group and  then execute rest samplers then it works for me ..but i think this is not a good approach

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your CSV Config Setting.

Ensure that it does not stop the thread & does not recycle.

[image: S]

---

Note:

Why do you have these many 'View Results Tree' listener? You need just 1 in the Test Plan level. Not for every sampler.

Comment: I think making thread stop is necessary.this suggestion is  not working

Comment: The sample get executed if I add another thread group but this is not the correct solution because execution order is not appropriate

Comment: if I make stop thread EOF is true then stuck in infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Please show us the results from the view results tree
It is possible that you are encountering an error, and if you are, and if the thread is configured to stop on errors, then that could be your problem

Comment: There is not result coming under view results tree

Comment: Trying back and forth but not getting the exact solution. Please Help!